# $\mathbb {Z}/\mathbb{Z}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, exact-sequence

In my lecture notes, it says (talking about short exact sequences) that if you have

$$0\to A \to B\to C\to 0$$

and you know it's an exact sequence, then $B/A\cong C$.

The notes then give an example: if $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $C=\mathbb{Z}_2$, then two things $B$ could be are $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$.

I get the second example, though not the first one. How could $\mathbb {Z}/\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}$ hold? Would the L.H.S. be equal to the trivial group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good question, when you have an exact sequence :

$$0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow 0 $$

You are not just given $A$, $B$ and $C$ but also a monomorphism :

$$\iota : A\rightarrow B $$

and an epimorphism :

$$\pi : B\rightarrow C $$

with the condition that $Ker(\pi)=Im(\iota)$ ($\iota$ and $\pi$ respectively denote the second and third arrow).

Then when you write $B/A$ is isomorphic to $C$, it is not rigorously false but is ambiguous since $\iota$ and $\pi$ do not appear anymore. Actually, it would be more correct (and I strongly advice you to do it until you are used to the notation) that $B/\iota(A)$ is isomorphic to $C$.

In your example it gives :

$$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2\rightarrow 0 $$

Where $\iota: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is given by $z$ maps to $2z$. Hence it follows that when you (ambiguously) write $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}$ you (rigorously)  mean $\mathbb{Z}/\iota(\mathbb{Z})$ i.e. $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.